# Keras TFRecord use variation of inputs to vgg19 model -- error graph disconnected

Tags: python, keras

I try to split a big image into small patches and use vgg19 to extract features from each patch, and then combine the features for model.

```
def create_model_tl(input_shape=(448, 448, 3)):
    print("start creating model - transfer learning ...")    

    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    
    ########## patches ############
    n_dim = 512
    patch_size = 32
    patches = Patches(patch_size)(img_input)  ## a function to generate tensor as [batch_size*num_patches, patch_size, patch_size, 3]
    num_patches = int((448//patch_size)**2)
    base_model = vgg19.VGG19(include_top=False, input_shape=(patch_size, patch_size, 3), weights="imagenet")
    x_pat = base_model(patches)
    x_pat = base_model.layers[-1].output
    x_pat = tf.reshape(x_pat, [-1, num_patches, patch_size, patch_size, 512])  ## convert shape to [batch_size, num_patches, patch_size, patch_size, depth]
    x_pat = tf.reshape(x_pat, [tf.shape(x_pat)[0], num_patches, patch_size*patch_size*512]) 
    x_pat = Dense(units=n_dim)(x_pat)
    x = x_pat
      
    flat1 = Flatten()(x)
    class0 = Dense(5120, activation='relu')(flat1)
    dropout1 = Dropout(0.2)(class0)
    class1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(dropout1)
    dropout2 = Dropout(0.2)(class1)
    class2 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(dropout2)
    dropout3 = Dropout(0.2)(class2)
    
    output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(dropout3) 
    print(output.shape)
    model = Model(inputs=img_input, outputs=output)
    
    print(model.summary())
    
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model
```

I got below error, could not figure out what was wrong.

[image]

Comment: try to remove this line x_pat = base_model.layers[-1].output

Comment: @MarcoCerliani yes, it is working, thank you.